# Android Wear modify "Open on Phone" button intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am trying distinguish if a notification was opened from the watch or the phone. Currently I am trying to set the `contentIntent` for the notification builder which also appears on the watch as an "Open on phone" action. I want to be able to set a different intent just for the watch so that I can add other parameters to the intent, but I cannot find the right way to do it.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        notificationBuilder
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .extend(wearableExtender)
```

I've tried to add a wearable extender and the action for "Open on Phone" stopped working. I want to know if there is a way to disable the "Open on Phone" button for the wearables and still maintain a `setContentIntent()` for the phone notification? I've also tried `setContentAction()` on the extender and "Open on Phone" button, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

There is no known way to disable the primary action button when you set a `PendingIntent` to the notification.

According to the [developer site for Android wear](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html), the primary action ***'Open on phone*'** button is automatically defined by `setContentIntent()`. 
So if you have `PendingIntent` associated with the notification on the handheld device, it is going to be automatically carried over to the wearable device with the default action button with same `PendingIntent`.